# gae.unindexed ignored on development server?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Are the "gae.unindexed" extensions ignored on the development server for App Engine?  I am peristing about 246 entities in one write call which is creating a total about 25 datastore put operations.  After some research I determined this was caused by the automatic storage of indexes.  The way you get around that is by adding the following @Extenstion as shown in my entity below(at least for JDO):

```
    @PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
    public class RealmEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

        @Persistent
        private String name;

        @Persistent
        @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.unindexed", value = "true")
        private String population;

        @Persistent
        @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.unindexed", value = "true")
        private String region;

        @Persistent
        private String slug;

            ...
```

However after adding two of these annotations on my entity, I still get the exact same 25 put operations.  My hope is that these properties are just ignored on the development server but will work in production.  Can anyone confirm or deny this?  Or maybe explain why it isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're not confusing datastore puts with datastore writes?

Making a property unindexed reduces your datastore writes, but won't affect the number of puts required to persist your entities to the datastore.  Are you seeing the number of puts via AppStats?

Comment: Yep I figured that out around 1 AM last night and forgot to update my post.  If I look at the column for 'Write Ops' in the development data store it was correctly updating as I turned off indexes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use objectify and the development server correctly reports the number of write operations I would expect.  It does take into account the properties which I have marked as unindexed.

I don't know how to fix your setup, but I can contradict your guess and say that your changes *should* be reflected in the development server write op counts.

Comment: Maybe it's something with my build process then.  I have tested both with the @Extension and without and it makes zero changes to the number of put operations reported by appstats.